# Logging effeciently for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I'm using **serverless framework** to enable hosting my functions on **AWS Lambdas**. For development, I'm using Kotlin.

Since I wanted to re-use resources ( like DB connection )  by a particular lambda, I have grouped apis which have the same handler function. Like all `/posts` related apis will be handled by `PostHandler`. Internally, based on `routeKey`, I'm assigning requests to concerned functions.

This means that for all `/posts` endpoints ( like `GET /posts/{id}`, `POST /posts` etc.) they all get logged to the same CloudWatch log group. This was becoming a problem. Since I was using an API Gateway, I also enable access logging at API Gateway level. This resolved my issue when I'm directly hitting an api.

However, I also have a service which would like to call these lambdas directly ( it could be lambda of that service invoking lambdas of my service or an EC2/ECS instance invoking lambdas of my service ). In this case, we would directly be using lambdas and no ApiGateway is involved. How can I maintain logging for different endpoints in this case?

Comment: Also be aware of [xray](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/).

Comment: You said "This was becoming a problem" without explanation - what problem did it cause? Perhaps CloudWatch Logs Insights might overcome that?

Comment: Basically I wanted segreration at endpoint level like for which endpoint I'm getting 4xx/5xx errors. If `POST /posts` throws a 404, at api gateway, I can fetch integrationID and based on that id, search in my loggroups of PostHandler. If I don't have these details, the search becomes more generic and more logs to go through.

Comment: If you're searching individual log streams manually, then I'll repeat what *Elliveny* said, and give you a link: use [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the actual question is, I think you're saying that it's hard to differentiate between the different use cases and requests?

I would recommend using structured logs (logging as JSON) and then using CloudWatch Logs Insights to query for the specific information you need. For example, you could log a request-id with each message and then query on the request-id later. You could also do the same with a shared id between other services which would give you end-to-end log visibility.